# Tomcat : Is there a standard way to create a thread per request?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I shoud write thread sensitive logic in servlet implementation.
(Thread level impersonation on Windows)

In this implementation, every request should processed by new Java (= OS Native) thread and thread should dispose after processing a request.

My question is, is there a standard way to stop tomcat reuse threads ?

Update

Finally I decide to write custom implementation of org.apache.catalina.Executor interface. It will be pre created thread pool but used thread simply disposed, not returned pool.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you want to do; thread pools (like connection pools) are there for efficiency: are you worried about information leaking from one thread to another?

Comment: Yes. I worried about information leaking because thread impersonation.

Some OS supports runs threads different privilege and I use it.
Im my implementation. Every IO operation and other audited native operation doing underuser's privilege. ACL and other permission will evaluated under Tomcat execution user (root or www) but remote user context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in `servlet` architecture every request is treated as a new `Thread` by the server so you don't need to maintain `request`. This will be taken care by any web server by default. You cannot change the configuration for not reusing the thread [here's the explaination](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/executor.html).

Comment: Is it default or standard behaviour?

In my simple servlet for test which runs on Tomcat 8.
Executor Pool is enabled and thread is reused.

Comment: Not necessarily: as the docs you linked say, Tomcat uses a thread pool, that it a set of threads, each one serving a single request. But the threads aren't respawned each time (they can be from time to time, though, i.e. to prevent ThreadLocal's memory leaks - can't find a reference ATM)

Comment: @user3188838 its default behavior and  you can change only allowed parameters which are linked in the document. also mark this answer as accepted if you think that it helped you :)

Comment: Sorry. I know one thread not process multiple requests in same time.
But I am never use one thread for multiple request go across time.

Because used thread's native context may be changed destructively (such as thread security privilege and so on).
And this case, some kind of thread context change is one-way. If I restrict thread privilege, can't free it.

Returning restricted thread to thread pool and reusing will cause unexpected result.

I seek a ServletContainer level solution of this problem.

Or I should all my code wrap our disposable Executor in servlet method.
It is not beautiful.